# MySQL Remote Access Communications link failure

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I developed an Android application using JDBC library that uses mysql.

Here is my full question: [Android app show "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExeption" while using JDBC to Connect mysql in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75044458/android-app-show-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexeption-while-using-jdbc-to-co)

when I'm using Eclipse to connect the data base it works properly, but when I'm wanna connect to data base using an Android application this error occurs:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

this is a part of my code that try to connect to mysql:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.106:3306/test","root","12345678");
```

192.168.1.106 is my pc's private ip that running mysql

I tried :

1.changed bind-address in my.ini to 0.0.0.0

2.deactivate firewall

3.I granted all the permissions and flushed privileges to '%' user

4.opened port 3306 on firewall

I tried all solution of other questions like this but error still there...

Comment: Please [reconsider your use of JDBC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).